# React: How to stop rerendering component on some specific state change?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing a component in functional components, where there are several other child components in it. There are different states which I am passing to different components. Some of these states have nothing to do with main component. But when I change these states these also causes to re-render of main component and re-render all the child components.

like

```
const [showSideBar, setShowSideBar] = useState(false);
const [showFloatingButtons, setShowFloatingButtons] = useState(false);
const [showCart, setShowCart] = useState(false);
```

Now these are passing to different child components like **showCart** passing to **Cart** component which setting **setShowCart** state in main component causes re-rendering of whole screen.
Please help if there is any way in **functional component** to stop re-rendering the main component which obviously cause the re-rendering of while screen while there is not a need to re-render the while screen.
I have MainHeader where I have buttons to set these components.

```
<MainHeader TabClick={(index)=>TabClick(index)} />
```

I am passing below one to **MainHeader** to update main component state.

```
const TabClick = (index) => {
  if (index === 0) {
    setShowSideBar(true)
  } else if (index === 1) {
    setShowFloatingButtons(true)
  } else if (index === 2) {
    setShowCart(true)
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Memo to prevent functional components from rendering unnecessarily. https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Or shouldComponentUpdate for classes https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

EDIT:
Return true in areEqual if you want the component to rerender

```
function MyComponent(props) {

}
function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {

}
export default React.memo(MyComponent, areEqual);
```

Comment: How React.memo will save to rerender main component where there are several states and on each event call any one of them getting change ?